# Get Image Data URLs on the fly while iterating

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array that contains several image URLs

```
const imgs = [
    'https://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1',
    'https://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2',
    'https://placehold.it/120x120&text=image3'
  ]
```

And I want to get those images as base 64 strings on the fly in preparation for a network request. What would I have to do to accomplish this using javascript?

I've currently tried:

```
const getDataUrl = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.height = img.height
        canvas.width = img.width
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
        resolve(canvas.toDataUrl('png'))
    }
    img.src = url
  })
}

let dataUrls = []

for(let img of imgs){
    getDataUrl(img).then(res => {
    dataUrls.push(res)
  })
  console.log(dataUrls)
}
```

But the promise does not wait for the image to load and resolve and I get an empty array

So I then tried a recursive solution:

```
let dataUrl = ''

const getDataUrl = (url) => {
  let img = new Image()
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
  img.onload = function(){
    canvas.height = img.height
    canvas.width = img.width
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataUrl('png')
  }
  img.src = url
  if(checkIntegrity()) return dataUrl
}

const checkIntegrity = () => {
  if(dataUrl.length > 0){
    return true
  }else{
    return checkIntegrity()
  }
}
```

which is unsavory because I had to rely on dataUrl being in the global scope and didn't work anyway because I get a too much recursion error when I run this.

Finally, I thought I could try predefining the onLoad function and passing the resolve function as an argument to that:

```
const onLoad = (img, resolve) => {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.height = img.height
  canvas.width = img.width
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  resolve(canvas.toDataURL('png'))
}

const getDataUrl = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
    img.onload = onLoad(img, resolve)
    img.src = url
  })
}

for(let img of imgs){
    getDataUrl(img).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    dataUrls.push(res)
  })
}

console.log(dataUrls)
```

which was my most successfull attempt, but it ends up returning `data:,` from every call so it isn't working either. Here is a fiddle with that code: https://jsfiddle.net/5o4Lq3bh/34/

Barring this, I'm at my wit's end. I also tried manipulating dom mounted images instead of javascript image objects and using a counter with a loaded check and a different recursive function but I get the same error, too much recursion.

My main issue seems to be the iteration. I am pretty sure for / of is synchronous, so I'm guessing the issue is that I can't pass around resolve willy nilly to other functions and expect to get valid results.

This would be easy to do on load but it has to happen on the fly, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't you try `Promise.all()` in the first attempt instead of iterating over the images and logging before the `.then()` callback is even called?

Comment: To be honest I did not know Promise.all() was an option to me. Edit: did not work, I get an array off `data:,` @AmitB.

Comment: What do you mean by "array of `data:,`? Isn't that the array data URLs that you wanted?

Comment: No `data:,` means the image is empty, it should be a base64 string

Comment: if you take a look to the console in your fiddle you see the following error: **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Comment: I don't get that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet and the third snippet you shared has some issues.

First snippet, your console.log will always print an empty array because it's outside the then statement.

```
for(let img of imgs){
    getDataUrl(img).then(res => {
    dataUrls.push(res)
  })
  console.log(dataUrls) // will always print [] because this statement should be within then function 
}
```

Third snippet, you are calling onLoad function, instead of passing it as a event handler

```
img.onload = onLoad(img, resolve) // this will call onLoad, this is not an event handler
```

The below code works, but this doesn't utilize the full feature of promises

```
const getDataUrl = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
    img.onload =  function(){
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      canvas.height = img.height
      canvas.width = img.width
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
      let b64String = canvas.toDataURL('png');
      resolve(b64String)
    }
    img.src = url
  })
}

for(let img of imgs){
    getDataUrl(img).then(res => {
    dataUrls.push(res)
    console.log(dataUrls.length)
  })
}
```

If you want a much clear approach then use the below

```
const imgs = [
    'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/pie.png',
    'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/pie.png',
  'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/pie.png'
]    

let dataUrls = []
let images = [];

for(let imgUrl of imgs){
  images.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
    img.onload =  function(){
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      canvas.height = img.height
      canvas.width = img.width
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
      let b64String = canvas.toDataURL('png');
      dataUrls.push(b64String);
      resolve(b64String)
    }
    img.src = imgUrl
  }));
}


Promise.all(images).then(function(){
    console.log(dataUrls)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/5o4Lq3bh/52/

Note: FYI, your fiddle didn;t work for me too, I had the same cross origin issue like everyone has posted.